# If a div has "clear:right", nothing should float to the right of it, should it?

Tags: css, css-float

I seem to have gotten confused as to what the css "clear" keyword means.

I have a number of div elements, all with "float:left". The second last div element also has "clear:right". I thought that would cause the subsequent element to go to the next line. But for me, it doesn't.

Here's my example:

```
<div class="Section">
    <div class="Thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="Number">0</div>
    <div class="Title">ShopTVC Wallace and Gromit WOA 6Apr11</div>
    <div class="Duration">00:00:32</div>
</div>​
```

Looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to make the duration ("00:00:32"), appear on the next line, to the right of the thumbnail (the blue rectangle).

I know that I could put the last three divs into another container div, but the purpose of this question is to understand why "clear:right" doesn't stop the duration from floating on the right of the title.

Here's the CSS:

```
div.Section
{
    overflow:auto;
    background:cornsilk;
    border:2px solid navy;
    padding:12px;
}

div.Section div.Thumbnail
{
    width:64px;
    height:42px;
    background:SteelBlue;
    foreground:Navy;
}

div.Number
{
    width:16px;
    margin-left:6px;
}

div.Duration
{
    margin-left:22px;
}

div.Section div
{
    float:left;
}

div.Section div.Title
{
    color:DarkGreen;
    clear:right;
}
```

And, of course, the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/8J7V6/3/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `clear` property doesn't prevent elements from being placed in that space after the cleared element. It prevents the element from being placed where there are already elements floated to the that direction before it. Adding a `clear:left` to `div.Duration` would make it be placed below the navy box. Adding a `<br/>` before the duration might solve your problem, or, as you already said in your question, you could use another container div for the last three divs.

Comment: You sir are the first one who actually explains the logic of the clear value in a comphrehensible way :-) you cleared up a mystery for me heh

Answer (score 5):

ahruss's answer is the correct one, but I also noticed no one really answered your question. Basically `clear:left` refers to left floating elements. `clear:right` refers to right floating elements.

Since your element is floating left, not right, `clear:right` won't affect it.

The other thing you could do is wrap the two text elements in a separate div from the blue box, float that container div in and the blue div, then when you float the two text elements, your `clear:left` code will put the date under the text still within your container div and not under the blue image to it's left.

Like this:

```
<div class="Section">
   <div class="Thumbnail"></div>
   <div class="TextContainer">
      <div class="Number">0</div>
      <div class="Title">ShopTVC Wallace and Gromit WOA 6Apr11</div>
      <div class="Duration">00:00:32</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and add this to your css:

```
div.TextContainer {
   float:left;
}
```

Add in whatever other visual styles you need.

Answer (score 1):

I have used **padding and margin**. If it is not possible to use in your case then the following solution will not be appropriate.

http://jsfiddle.net/8J7V6/5/

Comment: This is a bit of a hacky way of doing it, but it works. However, you haven't really explained why the `clear: right` *doesn't* work.

Comment: May be, since the div is left, so it should clear:left. I am not sure though. If i am wrong, please correct me. I am still learning.

Comment: @sarwar026, check ahruss' answer below. They explain how clear works.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't anything floating to the right of it. The Problem you're facing is that you already sent all your content prior to the time, and then you're telling the time to float to the left. **It's still floating to the left,** it's just stacking on top of the content that's *already there* to the left.

But yes, clearing to the right makes that element break down past all elements which are floated to the right before it. Clear does not affect elements after it.

Have you tried [using a simple `<br />` after your title](http://jsfiddle.net/Y8UHt/)?

Comment: If everything floated he could probably make more sense of it, but as you say with just one thing floating there's just one element bothering with the flow of the page at all. You either float or you don't, or it's a mess imo.

Answer (score 0):

`.Duration { clear: left; }` should work

Comment: That makes it break down *all the way* below the blue box.