# CSS Float and Clear

Tags: css, css-float

I have 3 divs, and I'm trying to position them the same way:

```
[1][1][2][2]
[1][1][3]
```

I use `float: left` for all divs and `clear: right` for [2] div, but the result is:

```
[1][1][2][2][3]
[1][1]
```

What am I doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/3y3k0/v2jaC/1/

Comment: Although you did describe your problem, it is greatly appreciated to be able to see some code. Consider adding some code so that your question will have a much higher value

Comment: The problem is because `[3]` is still `float:left` the browser can float/fit it on the row above.

Comment: Ok, I added an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/uKDNm/

The key to is to group `divs` **2** and **3** in another `<div>` element that must also have the `float:left` styling applied, that way `divs` **2** and **3** span vertically across `div` **1**:

```
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="col2">
   <div id="two">Two</div>
   <div id="three">Three<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remember the clear:right applies to the placing of the element to which it has been applied - not the other elements around it. Putting a clear:left on element 3 would work instead

Comment: Basically, `clear: right` means you are clearing the elements that are floated to the right. Since all your `<div>`s are floated to the left, the property will have no effect on the layout.

Comment: See the answer to this question for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099705/if-a-div-has-clearright-nothing-should-float-to-the-right-of-it-should-it

Answer (score 1):

Please find the answer here, http://jsfiddle.net/9mx7K/19/

```
<div style="float:left;">[1]</div>
<div style="float:left;">[1]</div>
<div style="float:left;">[2]</div>
<div style="float:left;">[2]</div>
<div style="float:left;clear:both;">[1]</div>
<div style="float:left;">[1]</div>
<div style="float:left;">[3]</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have 3 divs, no 6.

Comment: I think you have completely missed the point of the question - 1,2 and 3 are divs that must span according to the layout - you have achieved this by simple repeating the text '[1]' in a separate div which is not what was asked.

Comment: @Anna.P it's still the wrong link, please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `<div style="clear:both"></div>` to force-break a row

`>> [1][1][2][2][clear:both][1][1][3]`

Answer (score 0):

### What's wrong:

You can't use `clear` like that.

You need to `clear` the direction the `float` is going.

If it's floating left then you need to clear the left side and vice versa.

### Solution

Use a `.clear` class.

**(HTML)**:

```
<div class="float">1</div>
<div class="float">1</div>
<div class="float">2</div>
<div class="float">2</div>
<div class="float clear">1</div>
<div class="float">1</div>
<div class="float">3</div>
```

**(CSS)**:

```
.float { float: left; } /* Or float: right; */

.clear { clear: left; } /* Or clear: right; */
```

### Demo

Here's a <kbd>[live example](http://jsbin.com/oyafak/1/edit)</kbd>